# If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open, there exist compact sets $K_n$ such that $K_n \subseteq K_{n+1}$ and $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n=\Omega$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm proving the following fact in the context of holomorphic functions

> If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a domain and $f$ is a non-zero holomorphic function on
>   that domain then the set of zeros is a countable subset of $\Omega$
>   and it does not contain a limit point.

My notes say I need the following lemma:

> If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is an open subset then there exist a sequence of compact sets $K_n$ such that $K_n \subseteq K_{n+1}$ and $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_n=\Omega$.

I have a problem understanding the proof of this lemma which is very concise:

> If $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$ then we can take $K_n = \overline{D}(0,n)$.
>
> If $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$ then we can take $K_n = \{z \in
> \overline{D}(0,n) : dist(z,\mathbb{C}-\Omega) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$

Of course I get the first case but I don't see very well what's the idea behind the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case, $\mathbb{C} - \Omega$ is non-empty and closed, so every point $z$ of $\Omega$ has distance $d(z, \mathbb{C} - \Omega) > 0$ (I use $d$ for the distance, i.e. the infimum of all distances $d(z,x)$ where $x \in \mathbb{C}$).

The function $z \rightarrow  d(z, \mathbb{C} - \Omega)$ is well-known to be continuous on $\mathbb{C}$ or $\Omega$.

Now $K_n$ is defined to be the intersection of a compact set $\overline{D}(0,n)$ with a closed set (by the continuity of $d$) $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: d(z, \mathbb{C} - \Omega) \ge \frac{1}{n}\}$, so is compact.

As every $z$ in $\Omega$ is some finite distance $\le N$ from $0$ and has distance $\ge \frac{1}{m}$ for some $m$ from $\mathbb{C} - \Omega$, taking $ n = \max(N,m)$ ensures that $z \in K_n$. So it covers $\Omega$.